# How do I unbind a Mac from the AD using the command line?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, active-directory

Currently I am using the below command line to bind any Mac to my AD, and so far has been work perfectly.

```
dsconfigad -a hostname -u DomainAdminsUserName -p Password --ou "CN=Computers,DC=hello,DC=com" -domain hello.com -mobile enable -mobileconfirm enable -localhome enable -useuncpath enable -groups "Domain Admins,Enterprise Admins" -alldomains enable

reboot
```

Question, how do I unbind a Mac from AD to reverse the above configuration using the command line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
dsconfigad -remove -u DomainAdminsUserName -p Password
```

If that doesn't work, you may need to add `-force`.

Answer (score -1):

Works like a charm from the command line and Jamf

`dsconfigad -remove -u DomainAdminsUserName -p Password`